# How do I pass props a component rendered with Enzyme.js?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs, enzyme

I have a SongLink component that looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'

const SongLink = props => (
  <ul className='search-results__ul'
      key={props.result.id} 
      onClick={props.handleClick} 
  >
    {props.result.name} by {props.result.artist}
  </ul>
)

export default SongLink
```

I am trying to write a Jest test to test this component. My first attempt looked like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import { configure } from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-15'

import SongLink from '../components/SongLink'

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })

test('it renders correctly', () => { 
  const component = shallow(<SongLink />)
  let tree = component.toJSON()
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

I got this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` which I understood probably meant I was not correctly passing props in to my test.

Then, I tried this, the goal of which was to mock what I thought a prop would look like:

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import { configure } from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-15'

import SongLink from '../components/SongLink'

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })   

test('it renders correctly', () => {

  // This is where I tried to imitate the props and pass them in. 

  const songLinkProps = {
    result: {
      id: '6rPO02ozF3bM7NnOV4h6s2'
    },
    handleClick: () => {
      console.log('click')
    }
  }

  const component = shallow(<SongLink key={songLinkProps.result.id} />)
  let tree = component.toJSON()
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

When I run the above code, I get the same error as before.

I would deeply appreciate any advice on what I'm doing wrong, or what I do not understand here. Thank you!

Edit: It has been suggested that this question is a duplicate of this other question: [Getting started testing React components with Enzyme and Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44849587/getting-started-testing-react-components-with-enzyme-and-jest).

I don't think this is a duplicate. I know that I want to test my component using Jest and Enzyme. I just was having trouble with the syntax I needed to actually mock the props I need for my tests to work. The suggested duplicate is more abstract and conceptual. My question is about granular execution of those concepts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting started testing React components with Enzyme and Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44849587/getting-started-testing-react-components-with-enzyme-and-jest)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `SongLink` component that you are testing just requires an object that contains the following properties

- props.result.id
- props.handleClick
- props.result.name
- props.result.artist

You need to pass it when you `shallow` render the component you need to test. You can do it like

```
const songLinkProps = {
    result: {
      id: '6rPO02ozF3bM7NnOV4h6s2',
      name: 'sf',
      artist: 'sgs'
    },
    handleClick: () => {
      console.log('click')
    }
  }

  const component = shallow(<SongLink {...songLinkProps} />)
```

Comment: Thank you @ShubhamKhatri! Much appreciated!